# regex-find values with specific pattern

Tags: php, regex, find, pattern-matching

I want to find specific values, from an string.

I have a string like:

```
$str = '
[mytips id="101" zcode="Volvo"]
[mytips id="321" zcode="BMW"]
[mytips id="423" zcode="Toyota"]
';
```

I need to get all the values of attribute zcode. So I can get a list/array like:

```
Array(
[0] => Volvo
[1] => BMW
[2] => Toyota
```

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use regex in `preg_match_all()` at php.

```
preg_match_all('/zcode\s*=\s*"([^"]*)"/', $str, $m);
print_r($m[1]);
```